# Run 32 bit executable in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: ubuntu, kdb, ubuntu-13.10

Today I upgraded my computer to Ubuntu 13.10 and am fixing everything that broke. There is a 32 bit executable that I need to get working again. When I run it, I get this:

```
jim@main:~$ /usr/share/q/l32/q
bash: /usr/share/q/l32/q: No such file or directory
```

Previously I just installed `ia32-libs` to get it working again, but that is no longer in 13.10. I did some research and I see I need to install the 32 bit versions of libraries. To find what libraries it uses, I tried using `ldd`:

```
jim@main:~$ ldd /usr/share/q/l32/q
        not a dynamic executable
```

Here are the permissions on the file:

```
jim@main:~$ ll /usr/share/q/l32/
total 540
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Dec 28 19:26 ./
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   4096 Dec 28 19:26 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 542846 Dec 28 19:26 q*
```

So it is an executable.

Now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to install

```
lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

Guess I just needed a few more minutes of googling.